# How to get google plus contacts in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-plus

I have integrated google plus with backendless. Authentication is taken care by them. After successful login need to get google plus contacts in angularjs.

Please could anybody help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should be really close. Pass either connected or visible to the collectionName parameter. You may also need to add ?key={YOUR_API_KEY} to the end of the request.

```
  function getGPlusContacts(id, collectionName) {
        var deferred=$q.defer
        return $http.get("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/" + id + "/people/" + collectionName)
           .then( function(contacts) {
             deferred.resolve(contacts)
            return deferred.promise
        })
  }
```

Comment: Thank you Mike,but I got this response.                                                                           {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid string value: 'collection'. Allowed values: [connected, visible]",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "collection"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid string value: 'collection'. Allowed values: [connected, visible]"
 }
}

Comment: Sorry. I edited the answer. The collection name has to be specified.

Comment: what is collectionName here?

Comment: either connected or visible